# How do I dump a Postgres DDL into a CSV that can be pasted into Google Sheets?

Tags: database, postgresql, ddl

I am trying to create an output from Postgres that will do something like the following:

```
schema, table, column, type, attributes
public, table1, id, bigserial, not null primary key
public, table1, name, string, not null
...
```

As long as the output is formatted with the column headers, I will be fine if it's not CSV (I can export a normal query as a CSV just fine). I am having trouble wrapping my head around the right query.

The closest I've come is as follows. But it feels like I'm on the wrong track and there is a simpler/cleaner way of doing this. I am also not currently getting a single row per table column (which is what I would like).

```
SELECT table_schema || ',' || table_name || ',' || 
    string_agg(column_list.column_expr, ';'  || '') || 
    '' || ');'
FROM (
  SELECT table_schema, table_name, ' ' || column_name || ',' || data_type || 
       coalesce('(' || character_maximum_length || ')', ', ') || 
       case when is_nullable = 'YES' then '' else ' NOT NULL' end as column_expr
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE table_schema = 'public' 
  ORDER BY ordinal_position) column_list
  group by table_schema,table_name;
```

Comment: What tool are you using to access your database, most have capability to export DDL. From psql command line use \d+ and pipe result to text file. I would also suggest a CVS is not a good format for DDL just plan text would be better.

Comment: I'm using DBeaver. That's why I can easily get the output to a CSV. But I want the DDL in the specific format above which is the gist of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I was overthinking this a bit. Here is the final SQL I ended up using:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_list.column_name, column_list.column_expr
FROM (
  SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name, data_type || 
       coalesce('(' || character_maximum_length, ' ') || 
       case when is_nullable = 'YES' then '' else ' NOT NULL' end as column_expr
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE table_schema = 'public' 
  ORDER BY table_name, column_name) column_list;
```